# 3rd / breaks the rewrite in restfull .htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can somone explain why this works:

http://sccatdev.office.dig/deploy/ajax/Test

But this not:

http://sccatdev.office.dig/deploy/ajax/Test/Article

For this simple .htaccess located in the deploy folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ /deploy/ajax/handler.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As far I am aware this rule should rewrite all requests from its root folder /ajax to the handler file. Why is the first one working and the second one not? And how can i make it work Oo? Google was not korporative in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will work for you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /deploy/ajax/handler.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Just changed "^" to "^(.*)$"

Comment: Sadly no. The old one still works but the other one i get page not found.

Comment: do you have any htaccess file in "/deploy/ajax/" ??

Comment: i would suggest you to put the htaccess file in "deploy/ajax/" directory.. then change "/deploy/ajax/handler.php" to "handler.php"
try

Comment: It is in the /ajax folder. and it works you have to use the whole url if you use the ^

Comment: ook it works with handler.php to.... lol. But it still breaks with deploy/ajax/Test/Article

Comment: try adding this line also.. "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d"
code is not incorrect.. maybe there is some technical issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131564/discussion-between-abdullah-mallik-and-sangoku).

Comment: Just fwi. Server fault. Vm restart caused it to work again... no idea why.

Comment: It happens maybe because of cache. When you restart the cache gets deleted that why it work after restart.. BTW cheers 